# How to implement whitelist firewall (every URL is blocked by default) using Squid?

Tags: squid

I'm struggling to implement whitelist firewall using Squid. Every URL (not SNI) should be blocked unless it is explicitly added to the whitelist (acl url_regex).

Squid is working in the intercept mode (traffic is redirected from VPN using iptables rules).

```
https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump \
    cert=/usr/local/squid/ssl_cert/myCA.pem \
    generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB
```

I can block all requests using http_access directive:

```
http_access deny all
```

but If I try to allow certain URLs, it does not work (every request is blocked). From my understanding, it happens because I'm blocking all "fake" CONNECT (CONNECT ENDPOINT_IP:443) requests.

Please advise if it is possible to achieve what I want using the default Squid build or I have to use ICAP or something?

Answer (score 0):

When I posted the question, I realized what my problem was. I needed to allow the CONNECT requests.

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8

acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow CONNECT localnet
```

solved the issue. The config is not meant to be perfect. I'm posting it just to demonstrate the idea.